# How to check built-in formatter/beautifier version? and does it auto-update?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, format, js-beautify

Somebody from stackoverflow asked me to check if I have the latest js-beautify in my vscode. But I don't know how to check it. Can you please help?

I read from one of the threads in VS Code that it uses js-beautify as the formatter (it's the one doing the 'formatonsave' etc.). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If it uses js-beautify, how do I know what version it is in? and does it auto-update to the latest version whenever there's a new one?

Thank you.

I already tried going through documentations and I also checked the preferences thoroughly, but I can't seem to find how to (manually) check for updates about plugins, especially the built-in ones like js-beautify.

Answer (score 0):

The default setting for `extensions.autoUpdate` in VS Code [enables auto-updating](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_extension-autoupdate) for all extensions. You can confirm this in your user settings or simply bring up the Command Palette (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and type 'auto update' to enable or disable it.

In the Command Palette you can also [update extension mannually](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_update-an-extension-manually).

The current version of every installed extension is listed right next to its name in the extension panel or under the Changelog panel.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The information you provided gives me a better insight as to how the extensions work, but unfortunately, it doesn't specifically answer my question.
My question is about the _built-in_ formatter. The one built-in right out of the box without going through marketplace or installing extensions. I'd like to know it's latest version, and configure it for auto-update etc. Thank you